# Maximum product for multisets with same sum

Tags: products, multisets, direct-sum

Given a positive number N, among all multisets (containing only positive numbers) with sum N, is there a reliable method for determining the set with the maximum product? For example, for N = 5, the following are some possible sets, with their products (i.e. all their elements multiplied together).

```
{ 5 }              : product = 5^1 = 5
{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }  : product = 1^5 = 1
{ 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 } : product = 1.5
{ 2.5, 2.5 }       : product = 6.25
```

I'm looking for a reliable method, for any given N, to find the multiset which produces the maximum product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** for positive numbers, the product is maximised for the same sum when the terms are all equal. This follows from the AM GM inequality.

---

Based on comments below, it seems you want to also maximise $f(n)=\left(\dfrac{N}n\right)^n$ among $n \in \mathbb N$. For this, you may note that the corresponding continuous function is monotone or unimodal and has a maximum at $x = N/e$. Hence, look for the maximum among $\lfloor N/e\rfloor$ and $\lceil N/e \rceil$.

Comment: I kind of figured that would be the case (although I wasn't certain). None the less, I can't figure out, generally, how to get exactly what that term should be.

Comment: $N/n$ where $n$ is the number of elements.

Comment: But n is unknown (to me). So, assuming you are correct, my question becomes simply, "How do I determine n?".